# Necesito que me de 2 cartas diferentes

Tags: python, loops, while, random, multichoice

Estoy tratando de hacer un juego de `poker` para jugar. El problema es que a la hora de decirle que del mazo me de dos cartas,me da una sola carta dos veces.

Por ejemplo me reparte `Q` de corazón y `Q` de corazón  o 5 de diamantes y 5 de diamantes. El problema es que es la misma carta. Yo necesito que me de del mazo dos distintas.Les muestro lo que he hecho a continuación:

```
palos = ["h","d","c","s"]
rangos = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]

Mazo = []

for palo in palos:

    for rango in rangos:

       Mazo.append(rango + palo)
Mazo=set(list(Mazo))

import random

while len(Mazo)>1:
  Mazo.remove(random.choice(list(Mazo)))
  #print(Mazo)    

#print(Mazo)
print("\n")

for Carta in Mazo:

    Jugador1 = Carta
    print("\n")
    Jugador2 = Carta
    print(Jugador1)
    print(Jugador2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es porque estás eliminando todas las cartas, excepto una en está parte:

```
while len(Mazo)>1:
  Mazo.remove(random.choice(list(Mazo)))
```

Y luego éstas imprimiendo esa única carta dos veces. Lo que yo haría es que al sacar una carta, se le asigne a un jugador, se imprima y ésta se elimine después. Ësto haría innecesario el for. El programa quedaría así:

```
palos = ["h","d","c","s"]
rangos = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"]

Mazo = []

for palo in palos:

    for rango in rangos:

       Mazo.append(rango + palo)
Mazo=set(list(Mazo))

import random

while len(Mazo) > 1:
    jugador1 = random.choice(list(Mazo))
    Mazo.remove(jugador1)
    jugador2 = random.choice(list(Mazo))
    Mazo.remove(jugador2)
    print("Jugador 1: ", jugador1)
    print("Jugador 2: ", jugador2)
```

Si quires que se guarden todas las cartas, entonces cada jugador debería tener una `lista` de cartas.

Si sólo quieres dos cartas, puedes eliminar el while y dejar sólo lo que está adentro. También puedes poner un número más grande en el while (como 40 o 50, para repartir menos cartas): while len(Mazo) > 48

Comment: esta buenisimo como lo mejoraste el codigo Luis! El unico detalle es que me reparte varias veces dos cartas a cada jugador y necesito que lo haga una sola vez.Como podria hacer? Cuando compilo por ejemplo me dice:Jugador 2:  3h
Jugador 1:  4h
Jugador 2:  3d
Jugador 1:  10d
Jugador 2:  2h
Jugador 1:  Ac
Jugador 2:  8h
Jugador 1:  Kd
Jugador 2:  Qc y necesito que lo haga una sola vez hasta que termine la mano y luego recien repartir la otra.

Comment: perdon me reparte solo una carta a cada jugador muchas veces y yo necesito que me reparta 2 a cada jugador una sola vez